# How to re link Excel spreadsheet to TFS after a project name change

Tags: excel, tfs

We recently had to rename a Project in TFS 2018, That went well as expected. I have a user that is using the Excel plugin for TFS and their excel document no longer can pull data from TFS. Is there anyway to fix it to reconnect to the new project name? It's not a simple spread sheet.  There are a lot of tabs that have inter dependencies on the tabs that can run TFS queries.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to fix it to reconnect to the new project name?

Based on my test , when I change the TFS 2018 Project name, I could reconnect to the new project name in the following two ways.

1. Use the "Refresh" option in the Excel.

[image: Project]

2.Reconnect the TFS and find the New Project name in `Configure -> Sever connection`. Then select the new project to connect.

In this case, you may get this error message.

[image: error]

To solve this issue, I try to restart excel and repeat the same connection steps. Then it could work.

**Update:**

You could try to delete the **VS Team Records** in **Excel -> Files -> Info -> Properties ->Advanced Properties -> Custom**.

[image]

Then you could connect the new Projects.

Comment: I tried to reconnect several times and I keep getting the same error.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @PatDelaney Do you mean that when you connect the project , you get the same error as mine? I have updated the answer. You may try to delete the vs team record in excel.

Comment: In my Document there are ~142 of those VS Team Entries. If I delete the first one in the list then the Team Ribbon grays out.

Comment: Tested it. You could try to click the `New List` option. Please check if you could connect the new project via this option.